# XForms 2.0 custom attributes

Tags: xforms

Can we add foreign attributes into the XForms 2.0 documents inside the elements that have the Common attribute?

I'm trying to add a custom attribute inside the model element but not sure if im allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you can always add foreign attributes and that it is not the intent of XForms to prevent that.

UPDATE: To clarify, I mean attributes in a namespace different from XForms.

Comment: Could u explain what you mean by namespace different from XFroms? I studied namespaces but cant grasp the concept or how to use them properly

Comment: Hard to explain this in a few words. You will have to do some homework. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace